# Checking pixel color in OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, pixel

I am currently working on a project with python and OpenCV. For one part of the project, I would like to check and see if one specific pixel (specifically the pixel with coordinate 100, 100) is not equal to the color black. My code is as follows.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('/Documents/2016.jpg')

if img[100, 100] != [0, 0, 0]:
    print("the pixel is not black")
```

When I go and fun in the terminal I get this error.

```
File "/Documents/imCam.py", line 5, in <module>
if img[100, 100] != [0, 0, 0]:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it states, you're comparing lists with multiply entries, which is too unprecise.

You'll have to use [numpy.any](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) like

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('/Documents/2016.jpg')

if np.any(img[100, 100] != 0):
    print("the pixel is not black")
```

Comment: Doesn't this solution only work for colors that have the same value for all of B, G, and R?  How could you compare to a different color?  Like `if img[100, 100] != [222, 12, 127]:`

Comment: `img[100, 100] != [222, 12, 127]` returns a list of booleans, `np.all()` returns `True` iff each element of a given list is `True`. So `np.all(img[100, 100] == [222, 12, 127])` will check if both colors match.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('abc.jpg')

if image[50, 50, 0] != 0:
    print("the pixel is not black")
```

Try this :)